# Using find to delete symbolic links except those which point to directories

Tags: linux, find, symlink

At the moment I recursively remove all softlinks from my current working directory like this:

```
find . -type l -delete
```

But I don't want to remove symlinks pointing to a directory anymore.

Is there simple way to customize the find command or do I have to omit the `-delete` and script something to inspect every found softlink "myself" before removing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already suggested in the comments, you can use the `test` utility for this; but you don't need `readlink` because `test -d` always resolves symbolic links.

```sh
# replace -print with -exec rm {} +
find . -type l ! -exec test -d {} \; -print
```

It might be slow due to the overhead from spawning a new process for each symlink though. If that's a problem, you can incorporate a small shell script in your find command to process them in bulks.

```sh
find . -type l -exec sh -c '
for link; do
  shift
  if ! test -d "$link"; then
    set "$@" "$link"
  fi
done
# remove echo
echo rm "$@"' sh {} +
```

Or, if you have GNU `find` installed, you can utilize the `-xtype` primary.

```sh
# replace -print with -delete
find -type l ! -xtype d -print
```